# custom UITableViewCell button isn't executing its function

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, viewcontroller

I have a tableview in my view controller with a custom cell. in the cell I have a function that is suppose to do something. I have a print statement that is getting executed.

```
@objc func cellButtonTapped() {
    cellText.backgroundColor = .red
    print("cell button tapped")
}
```

when I tap the button I do see in my console the print statement, but its not changing the cell  background color like I want it to.

this is the cellText in the tableViewCell

```
let cellText : UITextField = {
    let cellText = UITextField()
    cellText.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    return cellText
}()
```

this is how its layout is in the cell. I don't think its layout is important

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    contentView.addSubview(cellText)
    contentView.addSubview(cellButton)
    cellText.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                                 y: 0,
                                 width: contentView.width - 30,
                                 height: contentView.height)
    cellButton.frame = CGRect(x: cellText.right, y: 0, width: 30, height: contentView.height)
    
    

}
```

Comment: What is `cellText`?

Comment: please share full context

Comment: I updated the information. hope this gives you more context

Answer (score 0):

what I had to do is create a variable in the viewController with the value that the cell needs. in my case I wanted a bool value to be carried over.

```
var isBool : Bool = false
```

then I let the function for the button to change the variable value:

```
@objc func sendButtonTapped() {
    isBool = !isBool
    tableView.reloadData()
    print("send button tapped")
}
```

the function here changes the value of my bool every time I click the button.

I transferred the value to the cell with the cellForRowAt in the tableview.